# Assign a default value std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class A{
private:
 typedef std::function<void(A*)> Myfunction;
 Myfunction actionEvent;
public:
  A(){

actionEvent={std::cout<<"Hello"};
//declare a default function value here

};
void executeAction(){
this->actionEvent(this);
}
}
```

How to assign a default value in the constructor to myfunction?

Comment: The question remains: How is this different from initializing an `int` or `std::string`? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @BaummitAugen because it cant be done the same way.

Comment: How so? I see no problem.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so you mean to say i can write actionEvent={\\anything}

Comment: What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Because it is showing error.. or else i would have done that..

Comment: What error? If you have a problem with existing code, post a [mcve]. One can certainly assign to or initialize an `std::function` just as one would expect.

Comment: @BaummitAugen The code does not compile.. I cant put a semicolon inside the braces in the function definition inside the constructor

Comment: There we go, now we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign something that can be called like a function with a matching signature. `{std::cout<<"Hello"}` is not a function or callable in the first place, thus the assignment makes no sense. Try something like this:

```
int fun(int i) {return i;}
std::function<int(int)> foo1 = fun;
```

or

```
std::function<void(A*)> foo2 = [](A* a){a->something();}
```

The latter syntax is called a Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a constructor with a default argument and an "execute" member function in the following way:

```
class A {
 std::function<void(A*)> actionEvent;
public:
  A(std::function<void(A*)> actionEvent_ = {}) : actionEvent(actionEvent_) {}
  void exec() { if(actionEvent) actionEvent(this); }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b191190bf8cf117)

Answer (score 0):

Use an initializer list, and initialize your std::function with the function you want as default.

```
class A;
void my_func(A* a);

class A{

    private:

    std::function<void(A*)> myfunction;

    public:

    A(): myfunction(my_func)
    {}

};

void my_func(A* a)
{
    //use a

}
```

Or if you want the user to specify a function, or use a default non-null, function, do:

```
 A(std::function<void(A*)> func = my_func): myfunction(my_func)
 {}
```

In which case you can construct the object as e.g.

```
 A foo;             
 A bar(other_func);
```